# What does the "origin" mean when introduce the affine space?

Tags: vector-spaces, affine-geometry

This is almost the same question as [Origin in vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694032/origin-in-vector-space), and I am also confused by the statements in the wikipedia article of [Affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space):

> **St1**: Roughly, affine spaces are vector spaces whose origin is not specified.
>
> **St2**: When considered as a point, the zero vector is called the origin.

The **St2** is used as an answer in some replies to the post [Origin in vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694032/origin-in-vector-space). However, I am still confused.

My question is:

> which one is the affine space really don't care, the **origin** (i.e. the zero vector) or the **Origin point** (a specific fixed point in the space, to build coordinates)?

If the **origin** just means the zero vector, and affine spaces means a space does not need zero vector (the unit of vector space), it is clear and acceptable by definition. But in the wikipedia article of [Affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) (or other places introducing Affine space), we always mention Affine combination, which is independent of the choice of the **Origin point**. Here the **Origin point** means a specific fixed point in the space, which is not a vector (One may argue it can be treated as zero vector stick to this point, but a vector does not need to stick to any point). If it means the **origin** (i.e. the zero vector), then how does it connect to the Affine combination (which is independent of the choice of the **Original point**)

If it means **Origin point**, it does not make sense. Because the definition of vector space itself does not need a fixed reference origin point. In fact, an vector is configured by the length and the direction, we don't really need an origin point for any vector. A vector can be originated from any place, not necessarily from a specific "Origin". (Sometimes we may need the help of a fixed **Origin point** when we use vector as the position vectors of all the other points, but the vectors themselves do not need the **Origin point**).

Comment: In affine space $A$, there is no origin. However, we can turn $A$ into a vector space by just picking any point $z\in A$ and declaring $z$ to be the origin. It may help to carefully examine the definition given on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Definition

Comment: @ElliotG so, is the origin you mentioned a zero vector, or a point? if it is a point, I think the vector space does not need a specific origin point. It only need a zero vector.

Comment: "point" just means "element of a set." "vector" means "element of a vector space." In my comment, $A$ is an affine space, so it does not have any specified origin.

Comment: @ElliotG Do you means that because "vector" means "element of a vector space." so it is an  "element of a set.", so it can be treated as a "point"? And the origin  is a special point that can be defined (chosen) in any set? And what is the actual meaning that an affine does not need an origin. Does it means no point is special?

Comment: @ElliotG I am confused here because of the abstract definition of point (as you mentioned) and the point/or origin  when we really build the coordinates and drawing the picture. At least, a vector space does not really need that kind of origin (the origin of coordinates)